# R Array creation with very specific structure

Tags: r

I am a little bit stuck with one exercise in a beginner R course that I need for the following exercises (we should replace values of the previously created object).

Create object A, which returns the following when the structure is queried:

```
> str(A)
num [1 : 2, 1 : 5, 1 : 3] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
- attr(, "dimnames")=List of 3
..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
..$ : chr [1:5] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" ...
..$ : chr [1:3] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

Because I am a little bit clueless with the content, that is my beginning:

```
a <- rep(c(0,1),15)
A <- array(a, dim= c(2,5,3))
rownames(A) <- letters[1:2]  
colnames(A) <- paste("C",1:5,sep="")
```

Unfortunately I struggle with the object itself, I don't see how the array should be filled to be numeric and have a TRUE/FALSE content. Also the naming of the third dimension is something where I didn't find sufficient information.

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: This seems like content that isn't very useful...

Comment: sorry if I am using it the wrong way, had found some seriously helpful input on stackoverflow, I am not intending to spam in any way

Comment: The problem isn't your question! This is a great example of how to ask a homework question: you showed what you tried and explained the difficulty. What I mean is that this homework exercise seems useless. And possibly inaccurate with the numeric yet TRUE/FALSE problem. It is useful to be able to interpret `str()` output, but recreating an object from `str` output seems pointless.

Answer (score 6):

This exercise appears to be trying to teach you about array dimensions.

`array` has 3 arguments:

```
args(array)
#function (data = NA, dim = length(data), dimnames = NULL)
```

1. `data =`  is the data to be put in the array. Replacement is allowed.
2. `dim =`  an integer vector giving the "maximal indices in each dimension"
3. `dimnames =`  is a list of character vectors each as long as the corresponding dimension. (As an aside, the character vectors *themselves* can also be named)

Thus, the following would get pretty close to your desired output:

```
A = array(data = c(TRUE,FALSE),
          dim = c(2,5,3),
          dimnames = list(c("a","b"), c("C1","C2","C3","C4","C5"),c("X","Y","Z")))
str(A)
# logi [1:2, 1:5, 1:3] TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "a" "b"
#  ..$ : chr [1:5] "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:3] "X" "Y" "Z"
```

However, I do not see a way for `str` to print `TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...` while also being class `num`. Perhaps the lesson is incorrect.

You could also try your approach, but use `dimnames(A)[3]` to assign the third dimension's names:

```
dimnames(A)[3] <- list(c("X","Y","Z"))
```